# How to load .bash_aliases from perl/bash script

Tags: bash, perl

Lets say I have a perl script that setups a bash_aliases as follow

*source file: bash_aliases.sh*

```
alias w="cd /var/www"
```

*install.pl*

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
my $aliase_src= "${installation_dir}/bash_aliases.sh";
my $aliase_target="$ENV{'HOME'}/.bash_aliases";

if (! copy($aliase_src,$aliase_target))
    {
        print "Failed to copy file $aliase_src to  Destination:$aliase_target. Reason:$! .";
        die;
    }
[command required to load .bash_aliases file]
```

I should be able to go as follow:

```
./install.pl 
w
```

I dont want to :

```
./install.pl
source ~/.bash_aliases
w
```

I am unable to find command to load these aliases such that once the file is moved to home directory these aliases should be available to current script (install.pl) as well as all other script without running another command from command line e.g `source ~/.bash_aliases` OR `. .bash_aliases`

**Edit**
*auto_load_aliases.sh using `PROMPT_COMMAND` (trying to following l0b0, answer)*

```
#!/bin/bash
echo  'alias test="echo tested"' > $HOME/.bash_aliases
export PROMPT_COMMAND="$HOME/.bash_aliases";
```

this also did not work :

```
./auto_load_aliases.sh
test
```

What I expected what that auto_load_aliases.sh script sets the PROMPT_COMMAND , once it's set I have `test` aliase available.But that did not work.

Comment: What do you mean by "available to `install.pl`? Perl cannot use `bash` aliases, and aliases are typically used in interactive shells, not shell scripts which you might run, for example, via the `system` command.

Comment: `export PROMPT_COMMAND="$HOME/.bash_aliases";` doesn't do what you think it does. It *runs* the alias file instead of *sourcing* it, meaning that any aliases it defines are active only in the *subshell*. Please try my solution.

Comment: @l0b0 thanks, the question is how I can do it using from within bash script not from command prompt.

Comment: Why does your question include an irrelevant piece of code trying out `PROMPT_COMMAND` then? You need to *source* (not run) that script for the contents to have any relevance to the current shell. [What are you trying to do?](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/XyProblem)

Comment: @sakhunzai No, you put an invalid `PROMPT_COMMAND` in a random script file and ran it instead of putting the code I posted in `~/.bashrc` and starting a new Bash session.

Comment: bcz I tried to followed your question, sorry for misunderstanding

Answer (score 2):

`~/.bash_aliases` is not loaded by Bash by default, it is just a common convenience to avoid putting too much stuff in `~/.bashrc`. If you want the aliases to be available in new Bash shells you have to `source ~/.bash_aliases` somewhere in `~/.bashrc`. Some popular distributions (I believe Ubuntu is one) does this by default.

If you want to automatically `source ~/.bash_aliases` after changing it, you could try adding this in `~/.bashrc` to source it after each command:

```
PROMPT_COMMAND='source ~/.bash_aliases'
```

If your alias file is very complex, you could make this faster by using `inotifywait` and only reloading the file when it changes.

Another way of loading aliases after changing them would be to replace the current shell with another one:

```
exec "$SHELL"
```

Bottom line, *something* has to change to automatically load new aliases. There is no built-in runtime configuration option in Bash to do this (and even then you'd have to enable that option).

Comment: It seems I have to source ~/.bashrc atleast once. please see my edits

Comment: Just to clarify I just don't want to run separate command to source the aliases file or `.bashrc` , it should be done in single script ( if possible).In case of `PROMPT_COMMAND`, bashrc is updated which needs to be `source ~/.bashrc` .